# Sending Email in Odoo Record does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

I'm trying to send email in subscription modules, where if subscription is expired in 3 days, costumer will be notified about his subscription

i have tried following in odoo forum but no one work

```py
@api.multi
def subs_notify(self):
    mail_template = self.env['mail.template'].search([('id', '=', 67)])
    mail_template.write({'email_to': self.partner_id.email})
    if mail_template:
        mail_template.send_mail(self.partner_id.id, force_send=True, raise_exception=True)
```

odoo.exceptions.MissingError: ('Record does not exist or has been deleted.', None)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't search your email template with ID, Search it by name or anything else
this code will worked

```py
@api.multi
def subs_notify(self):
        mail_template = self.env['mail.template'].search([('name', 'like', 'Confirm Your Email')])
        if mail_template:
            mail_template.write({
                'email_to': self.partner_id.email,
                })
            self.env['mail.template'].browse(mail_template.id).send_mail(self.id,force_send=True)
```

if api.multi won't run, you must set your own trigger button,

Answer (score 0):

This would be a better approach instead of searching the template by name you can get the template id by ***self.env.ref***

```
    template_id = self.env.ref('your_module_name.your_mail_template_id')
    if template_id:
        template_id.write({'email_to': self.partner_id.email})
        template_id.send_mail(self.id,force_send=True)
```